# Duplicate class error on Build using Firebase Unity SDK 11.0.0

Tags: firebase, class, unity-game-engine, duplicates

Upon clean building my game in Unity version 2021.3.20f1, I currently get this duplicate class error:

```
stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.1.jar) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.1)
  Duplicate class kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractTimeSource found in modules jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.1.jar) and jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.6.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.1)
```

This goes on for many more lines, if I simply build and run my game without the clean build then launch it, i recieve this message in Android Studio when firebase should be launched:

```
logcom.game.gameRunner  E  Failed to initialize Firebase with System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Java class com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp class is included in your app.)) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Java class com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp class is included in your app.) ---> System.ApplicationException: Java class com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp class is included in your app.
                                                                                                      at Firebase.FirebaseApp.RegisterLibrariesInternal (Firebase.StringStringMap libraries) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

I have attempted using the Android resolver to delete then resolve libraries but this had no effect.

I also tried moving my game to a a different project, installing the the Firebase unity SDK with the Unity package manager and in another project as assets, this also didn't work so can no longer think of what else to do.

Any help appreciated